# How do you create an async version of a TypeScript function type?

Tags: typescript

I have a non-async function type in TypeScript and I want the same function type but async.

```js
// this is a function type
type MyFunction = (x: number) => void;
// this is an async version of the same function type, created explicitly
type AsyncMyFunction = (x: number) => Promise<void>;
```

`MyFunction` could be any function, so more generically it's `(...args: any[]) => any`.

```
// how do I get the async version generically without knowing the actual function type?
type AsyncWrapper<T> = (/*args of T*/) => Promise</*return type of T*/>
```

If it works correctly, I should be able to use `AsyncWrapper<MyFunction>` in place of `AsyncMyFunction` because the `AsyncWrapper` will be able to copy the parameter types of `T` and wrap the return type of `T` in a `Promise`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using the utility types [`Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) and [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype).

```
type AsyncWrapper<T extends (...args: any) => any> = 
  (...args: Parameters<T>) => Promise<ReturnType<T>>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4&ssl=4&ssc=104&pln=3&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgY2ASwPbKgXigAoAPALimUQFsAjCAJwEp8A%20KANywwBMBuAKEGhIUAIIBnEGgDq9AIZhI9ADwAVKBGLAIybuKIA6I3PoBzceTnIQzPGysg2BQkYMnz5AAom5VCNvpxNRZbNk96LCoMcQhlACV-RHpkVXBY1RYWITSxSTQIbnxcqVRZBSVlOCQ0TBwsgHp6qGaAPQB%20IA)

---

Side note: Nested Promises are always flattened in JavaScript. So nested Promise-Types also don't make much sense in TypeScript. If you may also pass functions that already return a `Promise` to this generic type, you may want to keep their return type as is.

```
type AsyncWrapper<T extends (...args: any) => any> = 
  (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T> extends infer U extends Promise<any> 
    ? U 
    : Promise<ReturnType<T>>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4&ssl=8&ssc=29&pln=5&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgY2ASwPbIIxQF4oAKADwC4plEBbAIwgCcBKQgPigAVGsaMBnCAB4AblgwATNgG4AUKEiwEKdNmQAmQiQpVaDFuyhjJs0wugBBfiDQB1RgEMwkRkIAqUCKWARkE-iQAdMEOjADm-JQOyCCsBBzRIBxEslBBIeGRXKEONBA%20jPzubHEcAEr5iIzIbuDCbhxePn4BGMgAZkxQAKqe3r7%20XDx8gkKJHKlpUAD8PVCTaZTcvALCFcBVNXXFbGZ1UFY2qBAS%20ESHdo7OTEJwSGiYOLi7APQvUwB60-L7F8cSmnO1kuThct2UDzU6le7zSX1kQA)